# Отличие между инициализацией одинакового кода на С и C++

Tags: c, gcc, c++, g++

Есть некий код, который может компилироваться и на C, и на C++, например:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Если этот код поместить в два разных файла: `test.c` и `test.cpp` и собрать разными компиляторами

```
gcc test.c -o c
g++ test.cpp -o cpp
```

будет ли различие в инициализации программы? Конкретно, будет ли различие в инициализации статических данных? И имеет ли значение для загрузчика, чем именно скомпилирован код, gcc или g++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно будет разница. Это касается и инициализации статических данных и инициализации рантайма.